# Logstash error handling in exec-input

Tags: logstash

How can I detect errors and non-zero exit codes when executing scripts in the input, e.g exec-input?

I'm using logstash for various tasks, for example node monitoring by calling a shell or python-script which returns some metrics. However, time to time the scripts fails, usually with exit code 1.

The problem is that Logstash just ignores the failure so the failed command is unnoticed.

Is there any way I can intercept the failure in some way, to at least log an error?

Simple case:

```
$ cat myexit.sh
#!/bin/bash
exit 1


$ logstash -e 'input { exec { command => "./myexit.sh"  interval=> 10 } } output { stdout {} }' -v
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 1
Registering Exec Input {:type=>nil, :command=>"./myexit.sh", :interval=>10, :level=>:info}
Starting pipeline {:id=>"base", :pipeline_workers=>1, :batch_size=>125, :batch_delay=>5, :max_inflight=>125, :level=>:info}
Pipeline started {:level=>:info}
Logstash startup completed
Running exec {:command=>"./myexit.sh", :level=>:info}
Command completed {:command=>"./myexit.sh", :duration=>0.038, :level=>:info}
2016-03-07T15:05:12.401Z 6755322742e7
```

No sign of that an error occured...

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in [the code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-exec/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/exec.rb#L76), exec{} reads the output of the script until the pipe is closed.  The only error handling is if something in the ruby code throws an error or exception.

You should open [an issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-exec/issues) to request this feature.

Comment: Good idea. Created https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-exec/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to make the script write to stderr:

```
$cat myexit.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "THIS IS TEXT SENT TO STDOUT"
>&2 echo "THIS IS TEXT SENT TO STDERR"
```

Then when starting logstash, the script's stderr will be in the stdout of logstash:

```
logstash agent -e 'input { exec { command => "myexit.sh"  interval=> 10 } } \
 output {  null { }}' -v -l /config-dir/out.log  > out.stdout
```

The stdout output:

```
$ cat out.stdout
Sending logstash logs to /config-dir/out.log.
THIS IS TEXT SENT TO STDERR
```

However, it would have been nice to have access to the script's exit code in some way, but I can live without that for now.

I have logstash installed as a service, which overwrites the stdout-logs every time it starts, so I plan to make a logstash-conf which tails the logs of logstash and sends them to a suitable place but that's another story